# Getting right projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a world map shapefile and I can only seem to get two results, both of which are half right.

The first, using a projection like EPSG:3857, I get a map that doesn't cut the east tip of Russia off, but does include a weird bar streaming across the whole earth:

[image]

On another projection, I get this, but with the Russia getting cut up problem (which I think looks a bit odd):

[image]

This seems to replicate no matter what Shapefile I use, so I'm guessing it's the projection?

Comment: not sure, but your shapefile's geometries could be wrong. What is the source ? try EPSG:4326 which  is another  worldwilde projection mostly used.

Comment: Unforunately that proejction isn't working either. I've tried about 4 four different mapfiles. From Carto, this one: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7a8585998b7f470b85235dcdb560c7e2, one from here http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php, and another from here: http://www.gadm.org/version2

Comment: Your second example appears correct. The 'cut line' is at 180 degrees and the map is centred on 0 degrees

Comment: the reason for this is that some polygons cross the antimeridian and wrap around. see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/239221/55203) for a fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are two problems. Firstly (your first picture) the datasource (from this website [esri](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7a8585998b7f470b85235dcdb560c7e2)) has some bad geometries [image: some bad geometries]

Secondly, some projections decided to draw from long -180°W to 180°E. so that's why  russia is cut. It could be a result of a geopolitic conflict, but I really don"t know why they chose this line.
If you need to get Russia "United" on a worldwide map, you can use Polar projection , but forget the south...

[image: from polar projection]

Project the earth is a set of compromises.

Some cartographers used a trick as you can see on this picture
[image: the tricks] 
[image]
(here earth has more than  360° ...)

Comment: That all makes sense. Thanks a ton for your help on this.