# GeoServer polygon artifacts on GeoPackage

Tags: geoserver, geopackage, vector-layer, rendering

I am brand new to GeoServer (2.23.1) and have it running on a Debian 11 Podman container. I can access all the sample data, which all renders as expected.

I am following the GeoServer Getting Started guide, and this tutorial on : https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/gettingstarted/geopkg-quickstart/index.html

I downloaded the [GeoPackage directly from NaturalEarth](https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/packages/natural_earth_vector.gpkg.zip), and confirmed the geometry seems to be good in QGIS, but when I add it as a layer in GeoServer, I get these weird artifacts, like some of the polygon points are drawn out of order. It seems to only happen with the polygon layers, as polyline layers from the same GeoPackage did not produce the same result.

I've search around but can't find anything that resembles this issue, and I'm not even sure how to describe it.

Is this a bug?

I'd be happy to file a bug report but wanted to get some feedback first.

[image: GeoServer GeoPackage Polygon Artifacts]

Comment: Your polygons exceed the edges of your projection

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks for your reply. The tutorial doesn't mention anything about projection, and the Bounding Boxes are defined by the data, so I'm not getting how that's related. Could you perhaps clarify what you mean and/or link to some documentation?

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/239221/79